# Generalized left (right) inverse of a function

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Let $f:A\to B$ be a function.

I know that a function $g:B\to A$ such that $g\circ f=i_A$ is said to be a left inverse of the function $f$.

On the other hand a function $h:B\to A$ such that $f\circ h=i_B$ is said to be a right inverse of the function $f$.

Where $i_A$ and $i_B$ are the identity functions on the sets $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Recently I come across a term 'generalized left (right) inverse' and a claim that says :
**A left inverse is also a generalized left inverse.**

Can anyone please help me understand the term (definition would be sufficient).

I know there is a concept of 'generalized inverse' for matrix operations.
Is that concept somehow related here too?

Comment: Yes, related. There can be more generalization of (left) inverses, and of course, any X should also be a generalized X. A usual definition that $y$ is a generalized inverse of $x$ (for matrices, but also making sense in any *semigroup*) is to impose one or both of the following conditions: $xyx=x, \ yxy=x$.

Comment: Still not clear how the idea can be implemented to inverse of a function

Comment: By means of the *composition* of functions.

Comment: So what would be the exact definition of a generalized left inverse of a function?